# Someone is duplicating/reproducing my site what can I do?

Tags: copyright, negative-seo, scraper-sites, dmca

Someone has created an exact copy of my site.

At first, the code of his pages were identical to mine. 
A few days later he just replaced my internal links with the same links to his own domain.
At the top of his source code he uses some "Vodafone securenet" script connecting to my site.

At first I thought he was using embed or iframes or something to reproduce my site, but I have posted a new post and it doesn't show on his domain.

I have contacted the company that protects his whois info and I plan to issue a dmca with Google.

What else can I do?

Btw, this is obviously a neg seo case, since his site has no chance to appear on the search, yet it can hurt mine as duplicate content.

Answer (score 4):

1. If you haven't already, you probably want to verify your site on both Google Search Console and Bing Webmaster Tools.  Adding the verification will help the search engines recognize the legitimate site.
2. You may also want to consider adding metatags declaring the author and generator in your site's templates.  See metatag properties/values on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta).
3. Add and/or update Terms of Use Page
4. Add and/or update copyright date on site footer upon making any content or html changes suggested here.

Although dated, [this](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/find-remove-stolen-content/) blog post from Kissmetrics pretty much sums up the courses of action noted here.

Answer (score 0):

DMCA should be sent to the Web Host.  You can find who this is by looking on the Whois record for the **Name Servers**.

Answer (score 0):

If the content is similar then it can hurt your seo. But people copy other websites all the time to be honest atleast the design. As a freelance web developer I have worked with many clients who wanted to clone some famous website.

This may come handy https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en

[Then report a DMCA on google](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/dmca-notice?pli=1&)